# URL prams getting changed only after page refresh

Tags: angular

i wanted to get the query value of  `?edit=`  and append that value to my router link.

I can successful get the param value of the `edit`.

But issue is if the `edit` value gets changed from `true` to `false`, my router link is not getting updated unless i refresh the page.

Can you please help

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.urlValue = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams["edit"];
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a class="production_model_col" (click)="showCollapse()" [routerLink]="['/flow/PFSession']" [queryParams]="{edit: urlValue}">
    <span class="collapse_border"></span>
</li>
```

Comment: I think because its a snapshot of the query params, when its changed its not updated. you need to clarify how the query parm is being changed to true and false.

Comment: I got two menu `View` and `edit`, if user clicks on view menu `?edit="false"` same way if edit is clicked `?edit="true"` will be added to the PF session

Answer (score 0):

You used the snapshot of the queryParams, which is a one-time value. You need to subscribe to `queryParams` Observable like this:

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pluck('edit').subscribe(value => this.urlValue = value);
```

Comment: i did but `?edit=%5Bobject%20Object%5D` only object is getting added to the url

Comment: Did you use `pluck`?

Comment: Because `queryParams` is an Observable of type `Params`, which is `key: value`, thus an object, if you accidentally binded to the value, not `value['edit']`, you'll get an object in the url

Comment: So what i have to do now ??

Comment: If you did not use `pluck` on `queryParams` Observable, then just copy-paste the code example I provided, otherwise, provide more of your code

Comment: i just did what u mention in the example `        this.urlValue = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pluck('edit').subscribe(value => this.urlValue = value);       
`

Comment: Then please provide more code. maybe somewhere in your code something affects your state